# What is the difference between 'at first sight' and 'on first sight'?

Tags: meaning, difference

When I read my text book in my major, I read two idioms. One was **'At first sight'** and another was **'On first sight'**, so I searched in the internet; however, I was not able to find the exact difference.

I want to know the difference between 'At first sight' and 'On first sight'.

Comment: Can you quote your source with more context? "On first sight" is not a common idiom.

Comment: +1 this is interesting. I see OALD describing 'shoot on sight' as well. I have never ever heard that before. For me, it was *always*  'shoot at sight'.

Comment: 'Shoot at sight' is used more in India. Google Ngram shows 'shoot on sight' is used more extensively.

Comment: It's always 'love at first sight', not 'love on first sight'!

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. "At first sight" is the common expression in BrE and AmE, see Oald, sight, idioms  http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/sight_1?q=sight

"On first sight" is a rare variant, not in every dictionary.

Google Ngrams   [Link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at%20first%20sight%2C%20on%20first%20sight&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20first%20sight%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20first%20sight%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: This answer is good. However, I would stress that they are dialectic variants. And, I would hesitate to call "On first sight" a "rare" variant. I would disregard the Ngram in this case, as it might not accurately represent this usage. This is similar to standing "in line" vs "on line".